# ThreadLocal and memory leak -- why not always use ThreadLocal<WeakReference<T>> instead of ThreadLocal<T>?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, thread-local

There are several (doznes of) questions here on stackoverflow alone about how ThreadLocals cause memory leaks. I don't want to add to them. But after reading them and the flurry of answers, and after having run into a huge memory leak over retained ThreadLocal Map Entry values that were huge, and which I simply solved by changing use of `ThreadLocal<T>` to `ThreadLocal<WeakReference<T>>`, now I am wondering, why not always do it like that, or rather, why (in the world) did the designers of the original ThreadLocal use a WeakReference for the key (the Thread, I suppose) but not for the value? And why isn't there at least some scavenging housekeeper on the ThreadLocal map which would remove entries that have lost their key?

I know "why" questions are at risk of getting flagged and closed. But we learn from asking why? May be someone knows what I am overlooking.

So here is what I propose to use always instead of the naked ThreadLocal:

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class PragmaticThreadLocal<T> extends ThreadLocal<T> {

  public T get() { 
    final WeakReference<T> ref = (WeakReference<T>)super.get();
    return ref == null ? null : ref.get();
  }

  public void set(T value) { 
    super.set((T)(new WeakReference<T>(value)));
  }
}
```

Now, this seemed to solve my problem, and I thought, if we went this far, why would this not be considered a bug in JDK and fixed in the future that all ThreadLocals should have a WeakReference to the value?

Then, the first comment and answer told me that I was wrong thinking that the WeakReference would help. It does prevent a memory leak alright, but it renders the variable useless as it doesn't survive even one GC! Also, I was wrong thinking that the ThreadLocal is held if the Thread goes away, no, when the Thread goes away, the ThreadLocal will too. The problem is if the Thread is still there, then the ThreadLocal will still be there.

Many times we use static ThreadLocal, which is less of a problem (except for perm gen leak in web apps that you start and stop and "redeploy"). My problem was that I used ThreadLocal as an instance variable, and when the object instance went away, it didn't clean up after itself.

Would it be the correct way to use the finalizer method to clear (remove) these ThreadLocal variables? I remember that using finalizers to clean up files or other scarce resources is a problem, shouldn't be done that way, so for files we can often close them in a finally part of a try-catch-finally block. But for thread locals we can't really do that so well, because we didn't need them to be ThreadLocal if we could have them in a single statement block (could just use local variables for that.) Therefore, is it correct to clear ThreadLocals in finalizers? In 20 years of Java coding I hardly ever used finalizer methods. I guess I should start now?

But then zooming out, realizing that use of ThreadLocal is associated with memory leaks, I am puzzled why there appears to be no standard cookbook solution to the general problem? Isn't there some best practice coding pattern which would resolve all issues of heap and perm gen memory leaks known to exist around ThreadLocals?

In my own case, I resolved my problem without use of any ThreadLocal, instead, I just extended Thread to my own class that would hold what I needed and then go away when the thread went away, or be at least bounded and cleaned up when the same thread would be used next time to serve some other job. But I am still using ThreadLocal elsewhere and I want to come up with a standard practice on their use. Again, like with closing files.

Again, finalizer the right choice?

Curious why that is even needed. When an object holds a ThreadLocal, and that object goes away, now the ThreadLocal itself should be eligible for garbage collection. But it has created an entry in a ThreadLocal Map, and is it true that when the ThreadLocal is collected, it will not automatically remove its ThreadLocal Map Entry? If so, is that not a bug? Or is it again a misunderstanding of mine?

Because if the finalizer approach would work for me, then why do ThreadLocals not have a finalizer themselves that would remove their map entry?

```
class MyThing {
    private ThreadLocal _threadLocal;
    public void myMethod() {
        _threadLocal = new ThreadLocal();
        _threadLocal.set(value);
    }
    protected void finalize() {
      if(_threadLocal != null)
          _threadLocal.remove();
    }
}
```

So if I can do that, then why doesn't ThreadLocal have a finalizer method, or, again, I could use a PragmaticThreadLocal like this:

```
public class PragmaticThreadLocal<T> {
    protected void finalize() {
        this.remove();
    }
}
```

Should I do this? Of am I again mistaken and this cleanup is taken care of already by the ThreadLocal?

In that case, why would I have had a memory leak?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how ThreadLocal works. When a thread dies, its ThreadLocal values die with it. But as long as it's alive, why would it be entitled to let its referents be garbage collected?

Comment: @shmosel maybe I do misunderstand it. So, not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If the value always is a [`WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api//java.base/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), it would immediately become eligible for GC in a lot of the typical use cases where it is the only reference to the value - how would that be useful?

See the example in the JavaDocs of [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html):

> ```
>     import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
>
>     public class ThreadId {
>          // Atomic integer containing the next thread ID to be assigned
>          private static final AtomicInteger nextId = new AtomicInteger(0);
>     
>          // Thread local variable containing each thread's ID
>          private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> threadId =
>              new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
>                  @Override protected Integer initialValue() {
>                      return nextId.getAndIncrement();
>              }
>          };
>     
>          // Returns the current thread's unique ID, assigning it if necessary
>          public static int get() {
>              return threadId.get();
>          }
>      }
> ```

This would no longer work with your approach. It might return a new value every time, in a non-deterministic way, depending on the GC.

Comment: True, duh. I knew I might have overlooked something. So what we would need is a ConditionallyWeakReference which would hold a WeakReference condition to the Thread and the GC would check if the Thread is still there, and not collect the ConditionallyWeakReference. But when whatever we point to is gone, we get cleared too. How can one do this?

Comment: I can't think of any way to implement something like that in Java. I suppose it would require special JVM/GC support, as this cannot be expressed in refence semantics. The easier approach is not to use ThreadLocal if you don't want to couple the lifetime of the refered Object to the Thread. "Just" pass around the reference as needed, or use a DI container with appropriate lifetime scope.